# Is there any mathematical proof of fractal self-similarity?

Tags: calculus, fractals

When studying fractals, one of the properties named by Benoit Mandelbrot is the self-similarity (and it's variations) of the fractal objects.

From Wikipedia:

> In mathematics, a self-similar object is exactly or approximately similar to a part of itself (i.e. the whole has the same shape as one or more of the parts). Many objects in the real world, such as coastlines, are statistically self-similar: parts of them show the same statistical properties at many scales.[2] Self-similarity is a typical property of artificial fractals.

This can be easily seen in pictures:
https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4b/Fractal_fern_explained.png
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractal

My question is, is there any way to demonstrate this property in a 'pure mathematical way' ? I know Mandelbrot's purpose was exactly the opposite, to link and demonstrate all this theories in a visual way, but I think any kind of pure demonstration would be great to understand this objects. I haven't been able to find any research about this so I don't know where I could start.

Comment: What do you mean by "demonstration" exactly?

Comment: @Travis I'm sorry, english is not my native language so I may not express correctly. I mean something like proof or statement. In this case, a way to 'confirm' self-similarity.

Comment: For an example, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set#Self-similarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only prove selfsimilarity for fractal sets $K$ that are defined mathematically, e.g., the Cantor set, the Sierpinsky carpet, Koch's curve. In these cases $K$ is not only similar to a part of itself, but $K$ is in fact the union of (more or less disjoint) similar copies of itself:
$$K=\bigcup_{i=1}^m f_i(K)\ ,$$
whereby the $f_i$ are similarities. In the above examples this is evident by inspection. All these examples go under the heading [Iterated Function System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_function_system). See the literature quoted in the linked Wikipedia entry, notably Barnsley and Falconer.

If you require only that $K$ is similar to a part of itself (as in your quote from Wikipedia) then there are examples which you might not consider "fractal", e.g., the logarithmic spiral
$$r=e^\phi\qquad(-\infty<\phi\leq0)\ .$$

Comment: Christian is there any paper or book where this formula is used?

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I'm going to check and I will accept the answer.

Comment: I don't think that all mathematically defined fractals are self-similar. Here is a basic example. Take a random walk. Replace each unit length segment of that with a random walk that fixes the end points. Repeat ad infinitum.

Comment: Also, if you require only that $K$ is similar to a part of itself, you don't need to go to far to find non-fractal examples. Take a line.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to demonstrate that property mathematically because the property does not hold. Not all fractals are self-similar and not all self-similar objects are fractals. The rigorous definition of a fractal is an object having a Hausdorff dimension that is less than its topological dimension.

This post asks a similar question and the selected answer gives more detail: [Why must fractals be self-referential?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/870199/why-must-fractals-be-self-referential)